# How to allow everything to be stored in the mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem I can not define very good, but I guess the reason is something that stops me from inserting values into mySQL on a specific html value.

I use the standard

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO events (name)
VALUES ('$title')");
```

but my question is, if there is a way to make `$title` accept all the possible values/text?
In database "name" is `text utf8_general_ci`

Comment: your query already does this

Comment: [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). In your case you may need [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (Depreciated)

Comment: have you tried and it didn't work? if so what was the error

Comment: Use prepared statements

Comment: Avoid using MySQL extension, is deprecated. Give MySQLi or PDO a go and advance to prepared statements!

Comment: @krishkim you actually shouldn't. care to read other comments?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO events (name)
VALUES ('$title')");
```

But mysql_real_escape_string is depreciated and may be removed in future version of PHP.

Comment: The *mysql* extension is deprecated, not just that one function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [P.D.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO events (name) VALUES (?)");
$stm->execute(array($title));
```